# How to get conversion completions by date

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am trying get a total from completions by date, but conversions don't have dimension date, actually the query is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%xxxxxx&start-date=2013-10-20&end-date=2013-11-20&metrics=ga%3AgoalStartsAll%2Cga%3AgoalCompletionsAll%2Cga%3AgoalValueAll%2Cga%3AgoalValuePerSession%2Cga%3AgoalConversionRateAll&dimensions=ga%3AgoalCompletionLocation&max-results=10
```

Comment: have you considered adding ga:date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try use Query Builder?

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

You can select ga: date and ga: goalCompletionsAll

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3AgoalCompletionsAll&dimensions=ga%3Adate

Answer (score 0):

```html
#get report data
query.list <- Init(start.date = "XXXXXX",
                   end.date = "XXXXXX",
                   dimensions = "ga:date",
                   metrics = "ga:goalXXCompletions",
                   table.id = "ga:XXXXX")
```